# Node.JS(Typescript vs Javascript) vs Ruby On Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, performance, typescript

In simple words my question is 
1.Does Ruby gives same performace as Node with MongoDB?
2.With Node Typescript or Javascrit should use ?

I'm a .Net developer(ASP.NET MVC).Trying to create an Angular Project with MongoDB backend with using some MIT like licence. So I googled on them and I got 3 options

```
1. Ruby on Rails
2. GO
3. Node.JS
```

I have two questions here

1. Ruby on Rails is good in the sense it follows already well known MVC pattern for me. But while seeing the graphs in the Net the optimal language for Angular Mongo combination is Node. Is there any architectural difference(Same language or different language in server is not major constraint for me) in performance in Node than Ruby? If server performance with mongo will be same i will like to go with Ruby
2. I read some tutorials on Node. I started to develop in Javascript. After one small module sample development I found people uses typescript for server also as Angular. So i googled about using typescript on Node. Some are telling there is serious bugs on most libraries in typescript development for Node and most libraries for node is only developed in Javascript and not in Typescript. I gone through Node site and they are not telling anything about typescript other than javascript and ecmascript. So what is the industry standard here(Anybody worked Node.JS with typescript and faced any problem)?

Thanks & Regards
Binesh

Comment: Please give answers. Don't care on downvotes(After answering please go for it). I don't know why the question is invalid? Its a key question in my architecture

Comment: Your performance question is very vague and cannot be answered without a very specific test case and probably doesn't even matter which platform you choose so there really is no way to answer.  Typescript vs. Javascript is just one person's opinion vs. another.  Again no way to answer without just sharing opinion (which is off-topic for stack overflow).  So, all-in-all, your question is off-topic for stack overflow.  I know that may be frustrating to you, but that's how stackoverflow is structured.

Comment: You can write high performance apps in any one of the languages you have mentioned.  Your choice of language will not be your limiting factor.  I'd say that node.js is getting the most developer attention of the three you mention which doesn't necessarily make it better, but does mean that there's more activity in 3rd party libraries and more places to get support.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Binesh the answer to question is .

> why Angular Mongo combination is Node

The reason to this question , if you are using mongodb that means you are working in such are architecture where the table structure is not fixed , if fixed then also you need the database where you can change table(collection in mongodb ) easily .

Now why we use node.js with it , the node.js is the language which support json easily and the mongodb also suppor json format in table .

And also some of the functions of mongodb have javascript syntax like map-reduce .
That why node.js prefer .

And also the mongodb support huge data and node.js is the language which support highest concurrency over any language currently.

> As i talk about typescript

I perfer not to use typescript in server with node.js . No need of typescript in server side .

Comment: Any question you can ask